# Haskell - error by execution

Tags: haskell, warnings, monads

I try to write a this monad

```
data W x = W x [String]

instance Monad W where
return x = W x []
W a h1 >>= f = case f a of 
    W b h2 -> W b (h1++h2)
```

But, now when i will use this monad and try to write return or >>= in code I get by compilation the warnings:

> No explicit method nor default method for Prelude.return in the instance declaration.
>   No explicit method nor default method for Prelude.>>= in the instance declaration.

Does anyone know how to fix this warnings?

thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the layout of the code is exactly as displayed in your question, the problem is that your `return` and `>>=` definitions are not indented, so they are being defined as new top-level functions unrelated to the Monad class.  Indent them and it should work.